OpenCV on Raspberry Pi Bookworm: cv2.windowMove() is not working
Here's my code:
name = "Player"
cv2.namedWindow(name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow(name, 800, 600)
cv2.moveWindow(name, 100, 50)

cv2.moveWindow() does not  have any effect at all - seems like it has something to do with Wayland Window Manager which does not support moveWindow ..
I tried switching to X11 but won't get any Desktop screen at all. However, the console is still working for switching back to Wayland.
Any idea for a workaround?

Please make a proper [mcve] that has import statements and actually displays an image.

"Any idea for a workaround? " -- implement your own GUI, using whatever GUI framework works on your environment. You're in Python, and it's trivial to display an image with tkinter for example.

You're missing cv2.imshow()
Change 50 TO 100
Code:
img = cv2.imread("supra.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
name = "Player"
cv2.namedWindow(name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow(name, 800, 600)
cv2.imshow(name, img)
cv2.moveWindow(name, 100, 100) #<== Change 50 TO 100
cv2.waitKey(0)


That's exactly why I asked for a proper example that actually displays an image!
